# How do I tell a browser which password field to save?

Tags: passwords, input

I am working on a website that requires two type="password" inputs and I would like to know if there is a way to specify to the browser which one to save (for autocompletion)?

I know you cannot save two passwords per user without using an add-on (in Firefox for instance), but I would like to be able to specify which one to "Remember".

Comment: Are you building the web site yourself, or using a web site that was built by somebody else?